# Python os.system troubles

Tags: python

I am writing a program where you need to input a title for a file. If you want to delete the file, the command ss "rm name_of_file".
Here Is My Code:

```
    import os
    title = raw_input("What Will Your Title Be? ")
    os.system("rm", title)
```

As you can probably imagine, that is only a very small part of the program I am writing.
The Error I Am Getting Is:

```
    File "./texts.py", line 1446, in <module>
    os.system("rm", title)
    TypeError: system() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I am probably just wording this wrong, and some feedback would be helpful :)

Comment: Feedback: Read the error; you'll probably figure.

Comment: My Title Will Be `-rf /`. Please Consider The Implications Before Releasing This To Production. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The comma separates it into two arguments, so you are getting that error because that function only takes one argument. Change it so you are adding to the same string thus submitting just one argument to make it work:

```
os.system("rm "+title)
```

Comment: Thanks! It Worked Perfectly! That Was Only Five Minutes After I Posted This. I Appreciate The Quick Feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be exceedingly hard to implement safely. Consider the case when someone types `-rf /` as the filename to delete. I'd **strongly** suggest using the `os.unlink` function instead:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.unlink('-rf /')
...
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '-rf /'
```

This is a dangerous operation to attempt on your own. Let the standard library do the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do

```
if os.path.isfile(title):
    os.remove(title)
```

Comment: There's a race condition between those two lines. Better: just blindly `os.remove(title)` and catch the OSError exception if you care to.